Justification for differentiation under integral
Given a function I seek to find its derivative $$f(x) = \int_{\frac{1}{x}}^{\frac{e^x}{x}} \frac{\cos(xt)}{t} \, dt, \quad (x>0)$$
My question is regarding the justification of the differentiation under the integral sign rather than how to do it.
The theorems that I have at hand are the following.
$\textbf{Theorem 1}$
Let $[a,b]$ compact interval, $J$ open interval, suppose that $f(x,t), \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t)$ continuous for $(x,t)\in [a,b]\times J$. Then $F(t) = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t) \,dx\quad t\in J$.
$\textbf{Theorem 2 (For generalised domains)}$
Suppose there are majorants $g(x), h(x)$ such that $\left| f(x,t) \right| \le g(x), \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t) \right| \le h(x)$ and $\int_Ig(x)\,dx < \infty,\quad \int_Ih(x)\,dx < \infty $. We form $F(t) = \int_If(x,t)\, dx$ then $F(t)$ is differentiable and $F'(t) = \int_I\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t) \,dx$.
Now if we come back to the function I gave as an example if $x<\infty$ then the interval is compact it is also clear that the integrand and its derivative are continuous on that interval hence differentiation is justified as I understand. Now consider $x \to \infty$ if we use the second theorem a possible majorant is $\frac{1}{t}$ but leads to $x<\infty$. As I understand this is not possible as $x$ here is a variable. A similar issue occurs with bounding its derivative. Could anyone clarify what I am misunderstanding, or perhaps I am choosing the wrong majorants? Perhaps I have to assume that the interval is not generalised.
Thanks for any ideas and clarifications!

If you use the substitution $xt\mapsto t$, you get an integral that doesn't require differentiation under the integral sign $$f(x)=\int_1^{e^x}\frac{\cos t}{t}dt$$ This isn't just a trick, this shows how this is all fundamental theorem of calculus.

@NinadMunshi this is indeed quite nice, thanks for the insight. However, I am interested in differentiation under the integral sign and its justification.

I believe I have answered my question. Suppose we take my example function, we already satisfy one of the conditions of Theorem 1 that the $\frac{\cos(xt)}{t}$ and its derivative is continuous. Notice $x>0$, now $x$ is fixed so let some $x_0>0$. We can find and a compact interval, here we have $x\in[\frac{1}{x_0}, \frac{e^{x_0}}{x_0}] = J$. Now clearly, we have satisfied the first theorem conditions and thus, the differentiation under the integral sign is justified.
Note that this question does not need theorem 2, since the interval is always compact! We cannot take limits to $0$ or $\infty$ because $x_0$ is fixed no matter how large or small.
Theorem 2 is used when the $I$ is not compact, so when we have clear bounds for the integral. (proof is essentially the same as theorem 1 with a couple of extra steps).
Also, notice that in the theorem the integration is the other way around i.e. w.r.t $x$ and here it is w.r.t $t$,
I hope whoever uses these notions and is confused finds this helpful too.
